# Will suppressing breadcrumbs on mobile website work from an SEO perspective?

Tags: seo, mobile, breadcrumbs

We have an automobile website with pages in following hierarchy:
Home > Make > Model > Variant
i.e. Home > Audi > A4 > TFS1 Premium Plus

We are showing the breadcrumbs on our desktop page but not showing them on mobile websites due to space constraints. Is there any SEO wise potential downside by not showing the breadcrumbs?

It would be great if someone can share any official google document or relevant case study for this.

Comment: Don't known about including visible breadcrumbs on page, but you can use json(or other format) markup for breadcrumbs, see https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumb

Answer (score 1):

While Google use currently the mobile first paradigm, it is nevertheless recommended to use structured data on mobile pages. Just think about SERPs delivered to tablet users, where breadcrumbs are useful.

I would use an "unvisible" JSON format for providing structured data and let Google decide, which SERPs display them.

Regarding displaying breadcrumb on the mobile pages - i would maybe go with width-based media query, to let users see and use breadcrumbs, if their devices aren't too narrow.